# Trying to find solution for system of ordinary differential Equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I've got 2 functions:

```
A'[t] = (0.5/(1 + (B/k1)^n)) - 0.2*A
B'[t] = (1/(1 + (A/k2)^n)) - 2*B
```

with conditions of

```
n = 10; k1 = 0.5; k2 = 2;
```

and when t=0, A=0,B=0
I'm meant to find the solution for t=0 to t=120

I know I'm supposed to use the NDSolve[] function but I'm not sure how to place them in.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try here [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can numerically solve this with

```
n = 10; k1 = 0.5; k2 = 2;
interpol = 
NDSolve[{a'[t] == (0.5/(1 + (b[t]/k1)^n)) - 0.2*a[t], 
b'[t] == (1/(1 + (a[t]/k2)^n)) - 2*b[t], a[0] == b[0] == 0}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 120}]
```

That produces an interpolating function called interpol.

You can plot parametrically as

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. interpol], {t, 0, 120}]
```

Or you might just want regular plots of $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ as

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. interpol], {t, 0, 120}]
```

You can also evaluate at various values, for example,

```
{a[120], b[120]} /. interpol
```

Comment: Thank you! I realised the thing i was doing wrong was not grouping the {a,b} variables just before the {t,0,120} :)